# @Reqeustbody conversion issue - Springboot

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have two spring boot application running in two different spring boot version.

1. The consumer application ( 2.7.1) - Running in EST time zone
2. Rest Service (2.3.4 version) MST timezone

Consumer sends a booking date as a string value to REST service and rest service has @Reqeustbody to convert the request to POJO

**"checkinDateString": "2022-12-12T07:00:00"**

**public BookingRatesRS basicRates(@RequestBody BookingRatesRQ bookingRatesRQ ) throws Exception**

BookingRatesRQ object has bookingDateString attribute (String to hold the date in string format - private String checkinDateString; ).

The issue is when REST Service convert the json request to POJO using @RequestBody  the checkinDateString time is getting adjusted by 2 hours (EST to MST difference).

We tried converting the JSON request as String(@Requestbody String jsonrq). In this case checkinDateString is having proper value.

issue is happening only when we use @Reqeustbody and pojo.  Issue not happening if the Time in consumer application is changed to MST (same as Rest Service)

any thoughts?